# Does my claimant have a right to copyright audio from a popular reciter?

Tags: copyright, website

I got plenty of copyright claims on my YouTube channel from Qanawat Audio because I uploaded videos with Abdullah Al-Juhani's recitations in them. I wonder, were they right in copyrighting my video? 
 For your information, this is my channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJv0STX-xSkapow54orIJ6g/videos?disable_polymer=1

Answer (score -1):

Of course they can claim your videos if you use their copyrighted material.

Qanawat Audio is some big Arabic publisher and they have rights to many imams and their video and audio broadcasts and recordings. The recitations are simply part of those. As I see, there are many who share Abdullah Al-Juhani's recitations but apparently they do so illegally.

I don't think Abdullah Al-Juhani minds all that sharing, only Qanawat doesn't want you to make money off it.

In short: yes, they can because they have the rights.

Comment: The question asks " were they right in copyrighting my video?" and you respond "Of course they can claim your videos". This makes it sound like you're agreeing that they can claim copyright on the videos.  They can make a claim of copyright *violation*, but they don't have copyright over the video as a whole.

Comment: @Acccumulation Please try to understand what we are talking about here. Copyright violation would result in DMCA take down, that's not the case here. The topic is claiming the revenue of the video based on the rightful copyright holder of the audio. Very common thing actually. English is most probably not his first language and therefore it's pointless to pick on his wording. Instead you should try to understand what he means by them.

Comment: The question asks in perfectly valid English, "were they right in copyrighting my video?" to which your answer is "of course they can claim your videos". This is patently false, whatever else about the situation or your response may be intended or implied, and is misleading even when such intention or implication (that only you seem to be finding) is allowed for.

Comment: Does Qanawat actually own the recitations of Abdullah Al-Juhani?

Comment: Also, does it help that I'm using the audio to match with the mushaf? And also the English translation on some videos...

Comment: @thatonedodobird It's possible that Qanavat doesn't own the copyright directly but have signed a contract with Al-Juhani to represent him on YouTube. These companies try to find as many popular artists as possible. I would suggest you to record your own recitations and upload those instead. Translations - do you mean the Quran or other material like sermons and such?

Comment: Translations, I mean Quran. But i won't upload my own recitation because people only videos with *popular reciters* get views. But are my videos non-fringing because of this law: Copyright Disclaimer Under Section 107 of the Copyright Act 1976, allowance is made for "fair use" for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching, scholarship, and research. Fair use is a use permitted by copyright statute that might otherwise be infringing. Non-profit, educational or personal use tips the balance in favor of fair use

Comment: @thatonedodobird Fair use can be used as defence in a court only **if** your videos get DMCA take-down notice and you dispute it. That's why You-Tube has come up with this policy to redistribute revenue instead. You can't use fair use against You-Tubes own policy since your videos are still up and running.